# Images not showing up when rendering template from @app.before_request

Tags: python, html, flask

I am completing an assignment for Uni and learning how to use Flask for the first time. I got everything working, however there is one small issue that I ran into. The assignment requires that I render the login or registration page if there isn't a user in session to simulate good security practice of not letting anybody access the main site unless they have an account.

I have rendered the subaruregister and subarulogin before and the logo would show up everytime. Here is how it used to look with the updatepwd.html page as an example that works becuase I am just rendering it normally with @app.route and there is a user in session:

[image: page where the logo shows]

page where the logo shows.

Here is what it's doing when I render the template from the @app.before_request because there is no 'email' in session and/or I have 'logged off':

[image: page with logo that doesn't shows]

page with logo that doesn't shows.

Here is the beginning of the code from the main.py where I have the @app.before_request:

```
import time
from datetime import date
import csv
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, session
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
import logging

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="./templates", static_url_path='', static_folder='./static')
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 1
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'pythonisinteresting'

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if request.endpoint not in ('subarulogin', 'subaruregister') and 'email' not in session:
        return render_template('subarulogin.html')
```

The code for subarulogin.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Subaru Login</title>
    <a href="/"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='subaru_logo.png')}}" alt="Subaru Logo" /> </a>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Login form</h1>
    <form action="{{url_for('subarulogin')}}" method="post" >
        <div class="container">
                <div class="alert alert-warning"><h4><strong style="color:red;">{{ message }}</strong></h4></div>
            <br>
            <label><b>Email:</b></label><br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name='email'/><br>
            <label><b>Password:</b></label><br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name='password'/><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p class="bottom">Don't have an account? <a class="bottom" href="{{url_for('subaruregister')}}">Sign Up</a></p><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help on understanding why it is doing what it is doing and or possible solutions to look into would be greately appreciated because this has been both fun and a struggle bus to learn.